# Python Flask Restful, Store Variable 'Properties' Data

Tags: python, flask-restful

I'm using Flask-Restful to create an API to store [geojson](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) data.  Geojson allows for storing 'properties', and makes no restrictions on what these parameters can be (could store a color, a nickname, etc.)  I would like to transmit and store this data using flask-restful, but I'm not sure that I can do this with 'open-ended' data.  It appears when I use 'marshal' for my data, I need to specify exactly the fields I expect.

```
from flask import Flask, abort
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource, fields, marshal, reqparse

class GeoAPI(Resource):
def get(self, id):
    geo= session.query(data.Geo).filter_by(id= id).first()
    if (geo):
        return {'geo': marshal(geo, geo_fields)}
    else: 
        abort(404)

geo_fields = {
  "name": fields.String,
  "coordinates": fields.List(fields.List(fields.List(fields.Float))),
  "parameters": fields.String,     # String may be the wrong type, tried nested?
  'version': fields.String,
  'uri': fields.Url('geo')
}

api.add_resource(GeoAPI, '/pathopt/api/0.1/geos/<int:id>', endpoint = 'geo')
```

The data for Geo pulls from a SQLAlchemy query.

Is it possible to state that 'properties' is an object which can contain many different fields, or does this require me to explicitly state my field names?